# Azure Service Fabric - one app different named instances

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have Azure Service Fabric Application which consumes RabbitMQ queue and makes some calculations using data from sql database.
Connection strings for rabbit and sql stored in ApplicationManifest.xml via Parameters and then changing by different publishing profiles (I have different xml for cloud or local deployment)

Now I want deploy another instance of my application for another db/rabbitmq.
I suppose I must create another publishing profile, change config package version (e.g 1.1.0) and register new application type to cluster. But I mustn't upgrade existing app. Then I should create another app with version 1.1.0.

So there will be two apps in my cluster 
App for db2/rabbit2 ver 1.1.0
App for db1/rabbit1 ver 1.0.0

Is it appropriate scenario for having 2 apps with different connection strings?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/new-servicefabricapplication?view=azureservicefabricps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to only have one Application Type and then instantiate multiple Application instances of that type; each of those applications can consume a different db/rabbitmq. During application creation, you can pass different connection strings (db/rabbitmq) as [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration#specifying-parameters-during-application-creation).